# node.js in Eclipse - which plugin(s) are most people using?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, eclipse-plugin, v8

I'm mostly interested in server-side web development, though being able to redeploy some bits in Chrome would be nice.

I am currently running `Eclipse Indigo` on Ubuntu for developing mostly Java/Scala programs and to use git.

So far I've come across http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/ and https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/HomePage, but not sure which is preferable.

Comment: still no real joy with node.js in Eclipse, so have started hacking a mini-ide that's really just a syntax highlighting text editor with several terminal/shell panes - essentially the way I've been using Eclipse, but without the big footprint

Comment: Have you tried Nodeclipse?

Answer (score 17):

There is [Nodeclipse.org effort](http://www.nodeclipse.org/). Current version is 0.16
update site is
`http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/`

When you want to help in any way, [start by raising issue](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues)

> #### Features
>
> - Creating default structure for New Node
>     Project and New Node Source File
> - Generating Express project
>     with Wizard
> - JavaScript Syntax highlighting
> - Bracket
>     matching and marking selection occurences with background color
> - Content Assistant within one file
> - Go to definition with
>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click when [JSDoc is
>     used](https://jsdoc.app/)
> - Refactoring within one file
>     (<kbd>Alt+Shift+R</kbd>)
> - JSON files highlight and
>     validation
> - NPM support
> - Debugging - Breakpoint,
>     Trace, Variables, Expressions, etc... via Eclipse debugger plugin for
>     V8
> - Setting project properties for JSHint-Eclipse
>     automatically;        [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) 
>           settings template
> - Passing arguments to Node application and Node.js,
>     specifying environment variables values to use
> - Running
>     CoffeeScript *.coffee files
> - Running *.js files with
>     PhantomJS, MongoDB Shell or Java 8 Nashorn jjs util
> - Bundled together with Markdown Editor, GitHub Flavored Markdown,
>     StartExplorer (for system explorer and shell),        RegEx, Icon Editor,
>     MongoDB, RestClient Tool      and other plugins (20+ in total, check
>     update site and       Nodeclispe Plugin
>     List)
> - Support for Eclipse Juno, Kepler, Luna M3

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

Read http://www.nodeclipse.org/ for more & latest information.

Comment: It is very interesting news.
Nodeclipse exists for 2 years, and I have been releasing every month during 1 year. Read https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/#personal-message It is all open source and ready for anyone to come with new ideas.

Answer (score 14):

What I have tried

- VJET contains lot a bugs (in coloration, auto-competition ...). Could be better after a few updates. Node.js support is quite not up to date.
- Eclipse Web Tools does no support node functions
- NodeClipse http://www.nodeclipse.org/
- Netbeans have a [NodeJS plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36653/nodejs). Looks quite complete.

The chrome dev tools is just a debugger (and some chrome related utilities), not a fully usable IDE.

So far I would strongly not to use Eclipse for node.js project.

I'm using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for a while, and I'm very happy with it (And it has a node.js plugin).

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for the last 7 years, but sir... I am now using Sublime Text 2. Many upvotes!

Comment: @DeanRather no code-completions comes with the Sublime Text 2 though! That feature is important.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Aptana Studio (www.aptana.com/).

It's quite complete for javascript development besides it doesn't have node.js "direct support

It can be installed both as a standalone application or an Eclipse Plugin.

I've been using it for server and client development and works great for both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025825/is-there-a-nodejs-plugin-for-aptana-studio

Answer (score 1):

Try [Microsoft WebMatrix 2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

It is free and has intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

As of Eclipse Neon (May 2016), [Supports for Node.js comes as part of the JSDT](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article3.php).

The only prereqs are the installation of Node.js and npm.