# Is there a NodeJS plugin for Aptana Studio?

Tags: node.js, aptana

Is there a NodeJS plugin for Aptana Studio?

- At least for NodeJS code-assist
- And perhaps a way to create NodeJS project
- And local NodeJS debugging

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We have no NodeJS support currently. If this is something the community is interested in, it'd be helpful to file a feature request and vote it up: http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Since we are built on eclipse, you should be able to try out the instructions for NodeJS debugging on Eclipse, found here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

As for special NodeJs projects, there's no notion of that. You would likely just create a normal Web project. We do have the concept of libraries that you can add to a project, wherein you could point to js files/libs for NodeJS. We also has special syntax files for describing JS libraries/APIs so it can be integrated into our content assist. A good example might be the ruble we have for jQuery which contains that file for two versions of the jQuery API. Here's the 1.6.2 version: https://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble/blob/master/support/jquery.1.6.2.sdocml The bundle.rb up in the parent directory hooks up the file in the ruble/bundle.

My guess is that creating an analogous NodeJS ruble and building up an sdocml (xml) file that described the API would be the easiest way to get started. Sharing that on github and sending it to us would allow for others to contribute as well. There are docs for creating rubles here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+Ruble

Comment: @EdH, I believe it already does support commonJS spec. I use appcelerator's version of aptana and it works for me

Comment: Downloaded aptana a few days ago -- it seems to have every open source web app type _except_ node. Am disappoint.

Comment: This answer is getting close to two years old. In that time we have added support for CommonJS require in our content assist, so there's already some Node support there. There's just no explicit node project type.

Answer (score 16):

UPDATE: Project URL is http://nodeclipse.github.io/

There is [Nodeclipse.org effort](http://www.nodeclipse.org/). [Current version is 0.11](https://web.archive.org/web/20180806213125/http://www.nodeclipse.org:80/history)  see http://www.nodeclipse.org/history .

Recommended installation for Aptana users through [Enide - Eclipse Node.js IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-nodejs-ide)

> ### Features
>
> - Creating default structure for New Node Project and New Node Source File
> - JavaScript Syntax highlighting
> - Content Assistant
> - NPM support
> - Debugging - Breakpoint, Trace, etc... via modified [Eclipse debugger plugin for V8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromedevtools)
> - CoffeeScript support
>
> ### Installing
>
> Update Site : http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/

Read also [Hints (section Aptana Studio)](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/blob/master/Hints.md#aptana-studio)

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

Read http://www.nodeclipse.org/ for more & latest information.

Comment: I installed Nodeclipse on my Aptana install, and it works perfectly.  The only issue is that the inverted themes (white FG, on dark BK) don't seem to work correctly, so I've had to revert to classic themes.

Comment: One solution is to change color scheme https://github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/blob/master/Hints.md#aptana-studio

Comment: @BayssMekanique How did you install it? I get `Missing requirement: Nodeclipse 0.4.0.201305191444 (org.nodeclipse.ui 0.4.0.201305191444) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.1.102' but it could not be found`

Comment: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/46 Install JSDT first or use Enide to get NJSDT http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide

Comment: @BayssMekanique Ok, figured it out myself: To make it work you must have Aptana installed as an Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: @Lego that is also an option. For the latest case you can start from Nodeclipse NTS Eclipse distribution http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-nts that already has Nodeclipse installed.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

There are a few nodejs plugins as well as v8 javascript [Sublime v8] and standard ECMA-262.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if you're looking for a good IDE for node.js, you should definitely try Microsoft WebMatrix 2. It basically does what you requested to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was fed up of fighting with Aptana Studio and plugins and all this stuff... until I found out Sublime Text. Simple and wonderful.