# Java script editor or IDE for linux

Tags: javascript, linux, ide, editor

I'm new to node js and I am looking for a good and free editor (with good auto complete capabilities) or IDE (if it can rune nodejs by itself it would be great) for linux. (ofcourse a cross platform one is better :D)
any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: try netbeans or sublime ide

Comment: eclipse for javascript also better choice

Comment: This has more specifically about node js.
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038961/node-js-in-eclipse-which-plugins-are-most-people-using

Comment: atom https://atom.io/  is a good tool for js development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [sublime for ubuntu](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/sublime) and [SublimeText-Nodejs](https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs)

Comment: I use sublime for daily usage, it is not free and the dialog it shows (to buy it) is more than disturbing :D
I am a java coder and I use Eclipse daily, I really need a good auto complete feature :D

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend a full IDE.  I use Sublime Text for all my coding, but when you're trying to debug a 2000 line monster that's clashing with a CMS or anyone elses code, It's really nice to have variable highlighters available.  My vote is for Eclipse. You can't beat a solid IDE when it comes to nitty-gritty late night coffee grinds.